# The constructor Service(URL, QName, WebServiceFeature[]) is undefined

Tags: jax-ws, wsimport

I got **The constructor Service(URL, QName, WebServiceFeature[]) is undefined error** after I run wsimport for my client web service. Im using JDK 1.6. Please help.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You had produced code that needs JAX-WS 2.1. Version 2.0 does not  have WebServiceFeature class, and as result also not constructor in Service with such a argument type.

As you see, in Java SE 6 there is no such a constructor: [javax.xml.ws.Service SE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html), but for example in Java EE 6 there is: [javax.xml.ws.Service EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html)

Comment: @Sergey What do you mean? In general past versions do not reflect future changes. When 2.1 features are needed, 2.1 should be used.

Comment: Mikko Maunu, sorry for being stupid but how to set the version of jaxws - just replace jar files?

Comment: Yeah you need the new code, for an lib make sure it takes precedence over the jdk classes (in eclipse the order and export order must place the jdk below the new lib). Also, there is jdk 1.7.

Comment: I personally think that @Sireesh Yarlagadda's answer is the real solution whereas this answer is more like a hints on the problem.

Comment: @Fritz's answer could also be an alternate solution.

Answer (score 16):

add additional option "-target 2.0" while using wsimport to generate source codes for JAX-WS 2.0 and so on.

Comment: This worked for me, as I'm using Java EE 5, which overrides the version of JAC-WS.

Answer (score 7):

Change your JAX-WS in the preferences. It is compatibility issue for Java 6 SE and Java EE

[image]

Sometimes changing from Java 1.6 to Java 1.7 also solves this issue.

Answer (score 3):

remove jdk1.6 from classpath，then add jdk1.7 can resolve this issue

Comment: You can also replace jdk1.6 with jdk1.8

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add webservices-api.jar from JAX-WS 2.2 API, into /lib/endorsed. See the bottom of this page: https://blogs.oracle.com/ritzmann/entry/metro_2_0_on_java

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to switch from java 6 to java 7 you may need to change the 'Order and Export' Eclipse tab in 'Java build path' and put 'JRE system library' on top of the list.
If that works it could mean you have an old jar somewhere in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java version in Eclipse. Go the command prompt and check for the Java version there (command: java -version). 
Match both the versions and it should work just fine.